# Adding a new grant_type in ASP.NET Identity?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-identity

I'm using ASP.NET Identity in a Web API 2 project. I currently have it up and running fine for authenticating with a username and password using the following example:

```
grant_type=password&username=alice%40example.com&password=Password1!
```

And this is working fine.

Now, my service can be called from a mobile app and I want to give the user the option to be able to log in with a passcode. I've added two extra fields (passcode and device id) to the user table and have extended the UserStore to be able to retrieve a user based on this information.

My question is how to allow the user to supply a passcode? I need them to be able to log in with either password or passcode, so I was thinking of sending the following for passcode:

```
grant_type=passcode&username=alice%40example.com&passcode=1234&deviceid=abcdef
```

and depending on the grant_type I can either query the user store by password or passcode. However this throws an error (`unsupported_grant_type`) and having a quick search it looks like these are predefined values so I can't add a new one?

Am I able to add a new `grant_type` or do I have to stick with `password` and have an additional field in the post data stating if it's passcode?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding another `grant_type` doesn't seem to be a major issue. There is though: compliance. Every OAuth endpoint has a specific set of allowed `grant_type`s. If you add another one, you are actually bypassing the standard, which will lead to problems with others implementing it.